# Google play In app update api availability and uses

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

In  Android Dev Summit 2018, google had announced In app update API for the developers. Is it available now ? If so is there any example of using this API. I have searched for it but didn't get any example

Comment: Check this tutorial https://medium.com/grandcentrix/implement-an-in-app-updater-1f50fbc38416

Comment: @Shailesh thanks for the tutorial. I will definitely look into it. can you please let me know when the API offered by Google will be available or is it available already? thanks.

Comment: It was not yet release, as it only announced to be released. The best thing to keep track is to constantly visit the [Android API documentation news](https://developer.android.com/news) to keep track on changes.

Comment: did you find api or still need??

Answer (score 1):

Recently Google released an API for that functional, it is called [in-app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)
the video of the keynote is [here -16:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoLqSbV1ELU&t=980s)
there is a nice implementation [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-in-app-updates-on-android-57f1aee011cb)